# I get an error when trying to query over multiple databases in AWS Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I,m trying to join tables from 2 databases, when I try to write the full database name of one of the tables get an error message.

```
Select cust_id, substr(zipcode, 1,4) as postcode
from link-prod-business-core-datasets-gold-pii-public-pub.customer_pii_full

Error message:
line 2:10: mismatched input '-'. Expecting: ',', '.', 'AS', 'CROSS', 'EXCEPT', 'FETCH', 'FOR', 'FULL', 'GROUP', 'HAVING', 'INNER', 'INTERSECT', 'JOIN', 'LEFT', 'LIMIT', 'MATCH_RECOGNIZE', 'NATURAL', 'OFFSET', 'ORDER', 'RIGHT', 'TABLESAMPLE', 'UNION', 'WHERE', 'WINDOW', <EOF>, <identifier>
```

Any ideas how to overcome this are helpful

I tried to put the full database and table name in single and double Apostrophes but that didn't work.

Comment: Your table name needs to be quoted. Now it's read as link minus prod minus business ...

Answer (score 0):

try to use "link-prod-business-core-datasets-gold-pii-public-pub"."customer_pii_full"